# conflict 2 rewrite rule operation in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tow rewrite rule's that has a same beginning part.

Here is my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+?)(/)?$ ./handle.php?q=category&cat_name=$1 [L]      
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(/)?$ ./handle.php?q=post_title&title=$1 [L]
```

I would like to rewrite all url's that have category at the beginning like:

`/category/part2` to `./handle.php?q=category&cat_name=part2`

and all of url's expect the first rule, like:

`/posttitle` to `./handle.php?q=post_title&title=posttitle`

When I commented out the 2nd rule, the first rule works fine. However, when all of tow rules is active, the 2nd rule does not work.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule here.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /handle.php?q=category&cat_name=$1 [L]      
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /handle.php?q=post_title&title=$1 [L]
```